# Kivy ActionBar example

Tags: python, kivy

I was trying to find an example of the ActionBar in Kivy, but was unable to find one.

I tried adding it in the kv language with the below:

```
<MyApp>:
    ActionBar:
```

But I get an error the module was not found in the stack trace. Does anyone know of an ActionBar example or can anyone clarify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActionBar is only available in the development branch 1.8. and the example is at https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/actionbar.py